# How to regex number, and to keep comma, whitespace and dot in the output string?

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I've got a problem with a regex, I need to extract a string from text and keep whitespace, coma and dot in the number(if it is exists), example: Lorem impsum the price is:196 000,2545.20 $ blablabla, 
Output:
**196 000,2545.20**

Example2:2530002545.20 £,
Output:
**2530002545.20**

I did the following:

```
String exampleStr = "Lorem impsum the price is:196 000,2545.20 $ blablabla"
String result = exampleStr.replaceAll("[^\\d.,]", " ")
                          .replaceAll(/\s*$/,'')
```

Firstly replace everything that is not whitespace, comma, dot or whitespace(to keep it in the number), secondly removed spaces from the end of the string.
This solution works, BUT I want to re-do it in a more proper way, to keep that white space inside and remove others from the beginning and the end of the 'price'. 
Ps: I really don't understand how to combine these two regexes, looking forward to your answers. Peace!

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to extract a substring matching the regex you can use Matcher. To get rid or trailing space just trim the matching substring.
Try this out:

```
        String exampleStr = "Lorem impsum the price is:196 000,2545.20 $ blablabla2:2530002545.20 £";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d[\\s\\d.,]+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(exampleStr);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("'" + matcher.group().trim() + "'");
        }
```

Output:

```
'196 000,2545.20'
'2530002545.20'
```

Comment: Thanks. Very helpfull!

Answer (score 2):

This simple regular expression `\d([\d.,  ]*\d)?` directly ignores leading and trailing text and spaces, and keeps dots, commas and spaces that are between the digits.

The Java string for this RegExp is `"\\d([\\d., ]*\\d)?"`.

Regards.